# How to Remove unused CSS on litespeed cache wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

this is an unused CSS link. how can I remove to improve my site performance?

https://ehappynewyear2019.com/min/7f90c.css
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQuOj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve your site's performance consider using caching plugins. Also consult with your hosting provider to see if they can increase the PHP memory limit of your site.

Additionally you can try using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/scripts-to-footerphp/
That plugin will ensure the scripts load in the footer which may help with the load speed.

Comment: ok I understand that. thanks but 
when I go to check my site speed at https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights once checkup is completed.
i got error remove unused css So, how can i remove?

Comment: No problem, if you found this answer helpful please upvote it and click the gray checkmark.

Comment: check out this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQuOj.png

Comment: I seen that screenshot, but that doesn't tell much. You can try disabling plugins to see if that helps.

Comment: check this out https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fehappynewyear2019.com%2F&tab=mobile

Comment: Your site loaded in less than a second, 448ms. With a score of 87. YouTube.com has 64. Your site is even faster than YouTube. You no longer need to make it faster. That CSS loaded is coming from a minified file on your site. If it's not your theme then remove your plugins. However since your site is already so extremely fast you can stop trying to make it faster. It matters only if it is fast for SEO but that only is important if your site is slower than 5 seconds, your site is not in that category it is already extremely fast. Go sleep, no need to worry.

Comment: I know my site so fast.
actually I resolved all technical issues that speed tester had mentioned but this one is can't be fixed

Comment: You no longer need to fix it because it's already fast. The purpose of fixing is if it is slow. It is not slow.